# ABUnknownPersonViewController with UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I want to use ABUnknownPersonViewController with UIViewController .but apple library says that
Important: Unknown-person view controllers must be used with a navigation controller in order to function properly.

I am using this with UIViewController it will shows data properly(firstname,lastname) but i is not showing.

my code is

```
ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];

unknownPersonViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400);
unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
unknownPersonViewController.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = (ABRecordRef)[addressController buildContactDetails];
[self presentModalViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];

[unknownPersonViewController release];
```

Comment: Is you view controller is already in navigation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow Apple's recommendation on using navigation controller. You might make this work properly but there is no knowing when it will break in the future especially since we don't know how these classes are implemented. Consider this part of the API exposed by Apple and stick to it.